# NumPy array of integers to timedelta

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array of milliseconds in integers, which I want to convert to an array of Python datetimes via a timedelta operation.

The following MWE works, but I'm convinced there is a more elegant approach or with better performence than multiplication by 1 ms.

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2016-01-02 03:04:56.789101').to_pydatetime()
dt = np.array([      19,    14980,    19620, 54964615, 54964655, 86433958])
time_arr = start +  dt * timedelta(milliseconds=1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So your approach produces:

```
In [56]: start = pd.Timestamp('2016-01-02 03:04:56.789101').to_pydatetime()
In [57]: start
Out[57]: datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 4, 56, 789101)
In [58]: dt = np.array([      19,    14980,    19620, 54964615, 54964655, 86433958])
In [59]: time_arr = start +  dt * timedelta(milliseconds=1)
In [60]: time_arr
Out[60]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 4, 56, 808101),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 5, 11, 769101),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 5, 16, 409101),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 18, 21, 1, 404101),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 18, 21, 1, 444101),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 3, 3, 5, 30, 747101)], dtype=object)
```

The equivalent using `np.datetime64` types:

```
In [61]: dt.astype('timedelta64[ms]')
Out[61]: array([      19,    14980,    19620, 54964615, 54964655, 86433958], dtype='timedelta64[ms]')
In [62]: np.datetime64(start)
Out[62]: numpy.datetime64('2016-01-02T03:04:56.789101')
In [63]: np.datetime64(start) + dt.astype('timedelta64[ms]')
Out[63]: 
array(['2016-01-02T03:04:56.808101', '2016-01-02T03:05:11.769101',
       '2016-01-02T03:05:16.409101', '2016-01-02T18:21:01.404101',
       '2016-01-02T18:21:01.444101', '2016-01-03T03:05:30.747101'], dtype='datetime64[us]')
```

I can produce the same array from your `time_arr` with `np.array(time_arr, dtype='datetime64[us]')`.

`tolist` converts these `datetime64` items to `datetime` objects:

```
In [97]: t1=np.datetime64(start) + dt.astype('timedelta64[ms]')
In [98]: t1.tolist()
Out[98]: 
[datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 4, 56, 808101),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 5, 11, 769101),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 5, 16, 409101),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 18, 21, 1, 404101),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 18, 21, 1, 444101),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 3, 3, 5, 30, 747101)]
```

or wrap it back in an array to get your `time_arr`:

```
In [99]: np.array(t1.tolist())
Out[99]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 4, 56, 808101),
       ...
       datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 3, 3, 5, 30, 747101)], dtype=object)
```

Just for the calculation `datatime64` is faster, but with the conversions, it may not be the fastest overall.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: with a `%%timeit` check, my initial approach runs in 21.9 µs per loop, your first approach (`dt.astype('timedelta64[ms]')`) runs in 14.1 µs per loop and the approach using `dt.astype('timedelta64[ms]')` runs in 12.8 µs per loop